# Python: Find indices of the *first* match between two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to compare two arrays starting at the zeroth index to find the first time *any* element in arrayA matches *any* element in arrayB - and corresponding positions within each array.

The issue is, the code I've written is matching the *last* instance of matched elements - I'm not quite sure why.

Here's my code:

```
for a in arrayA:
     for b in arrayB:
          if a == b:
              indexA = arrayA.index(a)
              indexB = arrayB.index(b)
```

Say `arrayA = ['j', 'e', 'b', 'a']` and `arrayB = ['k', 'e', 'b', 'a']`. The code returns `indexA = 3` and `indexB = 3` (matching on 'a'), whereas I'd like it to return `indexA = 1` and `indexB = 1` (matching on 'e').

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you keep looping once you've found the first match. When you find a match you need to `break` out of the loop. Also, you actually don't need the nested loop.

```
for a in arrayA:
    if a in arrayB:
        indexA = arrayA.index(a)
        indexB = arrayB.index(a)
        break
```

Comment: Nice i think this is the best way! but you can use `enumerate` for `arrayA` and improve it !

Comment: I had that at first, but then setting `indexA` and `indexB` were unsymmetrical yet essentially performing the same task, which I didn't like.

Comment: with enumerate you get ride of `indexA = arrayA.index(a)` that has O(n) (for index function)!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `enumerate` which provides the index of each element with a `set` for `0(1)` lookups and just `break` when found, each `if a in arr_b` is an `0(n)` lookup as opposed to the `0(1)` of the set which for large data will be much more efficient:

```
st = set(arr_b)
for ind, a in enumerate(arr_a):
    if a in st:
        index_a = ind
        index_b = arr_b.index(a)
        break
```

Comment: This doesn't work. You break out of the inner loop but not the outer one.

Comment: I'm a little skeptical about the O(1) claim. Set provides O(1) lookups once the set is made, but it presumably takes *at least* O(N) time/space to build the set in the first place.

Comment: @MattKrause,  if you have 100000 elements in each list how many times  are you going to potentially check if a is in arr_b if no element from a is in b? `in` is a linear operation over a list so one pass over arr_b to build a set is going to be faster that 100000 passes over the list arr_b

Comment: The naive approach takes $O(n^2)$. Switching to a set gets you down to $O(n)$ to build the set, plus another $O(n)$ to query the second array agains the set (so...O(n)). Each lookup is O(1) sure; but the lookup*s* aren't.

Comment: @MattKrause, I really don't get your point  *Each lookup is O(1) sure; but the lookups aren't.*, this is a linear solution the other is quadratic.

Comment: I read your initial answer as claiming that using a set converted the whole thing to O(1) instead of O(n). However, that's my bad: you're correct that the double-loop version is O(n^2), and that using set gives you constant-time lookups, for an overall runtime of O(n).

Comment: @MattKrause, yes. Worst case scenario there are no common elements or the  first common element is towards the end of arr_a which will give significant  performance differences.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest an improvement in performance to [mattm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28948266/1025391). You can save yourself some (potentially a lot) comparisons, when you don't check the presence of the object in the list before asking for it's index, but rather handle the exception when the latter fails. N.B., in Python it's *easier to ask for forgiveness than permission.*

```
arrayA = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
arrayB = [8,7,6,5,4]

# assign default, just in case no match is found
indexB = None
for indexA, a in enumerate(arrayA):
    try:
        indexB = arrayB.index(a)
        break
    except ValueError:
        # item is not in list, continue search
        continue

print indexA, indexB, arrayA[indexA], arrayB[indexB]
```

Note that using a set datastructure, to find out efficiently if an item is worth to retrieve the index of, can save even more comparisons. Which is effectively what [Padraic Cunningham suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28948840/1025391).

```
arrayA = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
arrayB = [8,7,6,5,4]

# assign default, just in case no match is found
indexB = None
setB = set(arrayB)
for indexA, a in enumerate(arrayA):
    if a in setB:
        indexB = arrayB.index(a)
        break

print indexA, indexB, arrayA[indexA], arrayB[indexB]
```

The expected output is in both cases:

```
$ python test.py
3 4 4 4
```

The first match is on index 3 in `arrayA` and index 4 in `arrayB`, which is in both cases `4`.

Answer (score -1):

You could refactor this into a function (not a terrible idea, regardless), and then use return to break out of both loops at once.

`def firstMatch(arrayA, arrayB):
    for a in arrayA:
        for b in arrayB:
          if a == b:
              indexA = arrayA.index(a)
              indexB = arrayB.index(b)
              return (indexA, indexB)`

Alternatively, you could throw an exception as a poor-man's goto. Python tends to be more tolerant of exceptions-as-flow-control, but I don't love that idea.

There's a neat trick you can also play with "mismatched" if-else clauses:

`for a in arrayA:
        for b in arrayB:
           if a == b:
              indexA = arrayA.index(a)
              indexB = arrayB.index(b)
              break
         else: # NOT in-line with the if
            continue;
         break #in-line with the else.`

Finally, the C-like solution is just to include a second "guard" variable indicating whether you've found a match.

`found = false;
for a in arrayA:
   for b in arrayB:
      if a == b:
         indexA = arrayA.index(a)
         indexB = arrayB.index(b)
         found = true
         break
    if found:
      break`

Comment: Why would you use a C-like solution when this is Python?

Comment: It's admittedly not great, but it's an option--and one that's probably used in a fair amount of live code.

Comment: Just because code like this may be in production python systems doesn't mean it _should_ be there.