# Find the index of top most element common in two lists

Tags: python

Say, I have two lists

```
  retrieved = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "foobar"]
  relevant = [ "foobar", "baz"]
```

What the pythonic way to find the first element present in retrieved that is also "relevant"

So in the example above.. since "baz" is the first relevant object retrieved. It should return 2, corresponding to the index 2 in retrieved.

Thanks

Comment: possible dupe of [Python: Find indices of the *first* match between two arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948143/python-find-indices-of-the-first-match-between-two-arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a `for` loop

```
for i, item in enumerate(retrieved):
    if item in relevant:
        print(i)
        break
```

As a generator

```
print(next(i for i, item in enumerate(retrieved) if item in relevant))
```

Read more on [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: Also, I want to return index rather than the element itself.

Comment: @Fraz in that case, we'll use enumerate, and just capture the index.  Give me a second and I'll update it.  Are you asking if this would be faster using numpy arrays?  I doubt it.  If you're really looking for speed, converting `relevant` to a hashed container like a `set` is your best bet.

Comment: But it wouldnt work if there is not relevant item retrieved..
But i think.. i got the idea. thannks